# chart.js stored on spiffs not working (chart does not appear on webpage)

Tags: html, arduino, chart.js, esp8266, esp32

i am implementing a web page from esp8266 in access point mode. I have saved this html file and chart.js plugin in the data folder and uploaded to spiffs. the web page loads and reads Chart.js Sample but the chart does not appear. ANy ideas? thanks x

web server file located with data folder with index.html and chart.js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Chart.js demo</title>
      <script src="/Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

<body>   
    <h1>Chart.js Sample</h1>
    <div class="chart-container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px">
        <canvas id="countries"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script src="/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        var pieData = {
            datasets: [{
                data: [20, 40, 10, 30],
                backgroundColor: ["#878BB6", "#4ACAB4", "#FF8153", "#FFEA88"]
            }]
        };

        // Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
        var countries = document.getElementById("countries").getContext("2d");
        new Chart(countries, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: pieData
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

web server file:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

static const char *wifi_ssid = "ESP32";
static const char *wifi_pass = "testing1";

static ESP8266WebServer server(80);

static bool wifi_connected;

static void handleRootOld() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Welcome to the ESP8266 server test");
}

static void handleNotFound() {
  String path = server.uri();
  if (!SPIFFS.exists(path)) {
    server.send(404, "text/plain", "Path " + path + " not found. Please double-check the URL");
    return;
  }
  String contentType = "text/plain";
  if (path.endsWith(".css")) {
    contentType = "text/css";
  }
  else if (path.endsWith(".html")) {
    contentType = "text/html";
  }
  else if (path.endsWith(".js")) {
    contentType = "application/javascript";
  }
  File file = SPIFFS.open(path, "r");
  server.streamFile(file, contentType);
  file.close();
}

static void handleRoot() {
  File file = SPIFFS.open("/index.html", "r");
  if (!file) {
    server.send(500, "text/plain", "Problem with filesystem!\n");
    return;
  }
  server.streamFile(file, "text/html");
  file.close();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("\n\n### ESP8266 - Web server + SPIFFS ###\n\n");

  WiFi.softAP(wifi_ssid, wifi_pass);

  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to mount filesystem!\n");
  }

 if (SPIFFS.begin())
{
    Dir dir = SPIFFS.openDir("/");
    while (dir.next())
    {
        String fileName = dir.fileName();
        size_t fileSize = dir.fileSize();
        Serial.printf("FS File: %s, size: %u\n", fileName.c_str(), fileSize);
    }
    Serial.printf("\n");
}
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that code inside <script src="/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"> is executed?

Comment: You only show the html file which is the static content to be served by the ESP8266, what is your code for the web server (i.e. how does the ESP8266 serve the web content)? also what is your file structure and the files in the `data` directory that you uploaded to the SPIFFS?

Comment: BTW, you include `<script src="/Chart.min.js">` twice, the second one should be just an inline `<script>`.

Comment: `the web page loads and reads Chart.js Sample but the chart does not appear`. So did you upload the chart.min.js or chart.js to the SPIFFS together with the html file?